# SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer - How to increase Font Size?

Tags: ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer - How to increase Font Size?

From the tool --> Options --> Fonts & Colors we can change fonts for many windows. There is a drop down 'Show Settings For' where we can changes font for text in many area's but I'm not sure how to change the font for the Object Explorer. I thought it would be the tools window drop down selection but that didn't effect the Object Explorer. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How do we change the font in SSMS Object Explorer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using SSMS 2016, it will set use the font and size settings under "Environment Font" in object explorer (and in all menus etc) on restart of SSMS. Screen shot showing setting panel and result

[image]

Comment: Wroks for Sql Server Management Studio 2014 too.

Answer (score 44):

You can't change the font of the Object Explorer *on it's own* but you can change it.

1. Go to "Tools/Options/Fonts and Colors"
2. Under the "Show settings for:" dropdown choose "Environment font"
3. Set the font/fontsize to whatever you want (I use 12 pt Segoe UI)
4. Click "OK"
5. Restart SSMS

Comment: The Size DropDownList is disabled when I go to that location. Do you know how to enable that?

Comment: Ok if I choose a font then I can change the size. When I change the environment font other font changes such as menu's however the Object Explorer font remains the same. I thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't accomplish what I want which is to increase the object explorer font.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either (on SQLServer 2012). Did you you try this bevore you posted it? If so, what version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: This DOES work, at least in SQL Server 2012.  Object explorer is not affected until SSMS restart, however.  Thank you for your solution.

Comment: The default Environment Font for SSMS 17.2 on Windows 10 is "Leelawadee UI".

Comment: You have to select the font before you can select the size.  By default the font is set to "automatic," and you can't change the size until setting it to a specific font.

Comment: In SSMS 20.0 the change to object explorer takes place immediately

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I like larger fonts, they help me see clearly and avoid mistakes when reading all the tons of text and data.

My alternatives for not being able to change the font in Object Explorer:

1. Windows 7 has a Magnifier.
2. Add a Filter when finding a specific table among the many tables in a database. Right click on Tables --> Filter.

Answer (score 2):

In SSMS-17, Once you have navigated to Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors, Select Environment Font from the Show settings for.  Then the Font will need to be set to a different Font before the Size of the text can be changed. The Automatic default Font setting prevents the Size from being changed.

[Snip: SSMS-17 Before changes are made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5984.png)

[Snip: SSMS-17 After changes are made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQi82.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, and will not be fixed at this time.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691432/ssms-should-be-able-to-set-font-size-for-object-explorer-registered-servers-and-properties

Comment: Microsoft Connect, where everything goes to die.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic Including Microsoft Connect!

Comment: Still isnt fix  in 2024 disgraceful

Answer (score 1):

change grid result font
Go to "Tools/Options/Fonts and Colors"
Under the "Show settings for:" dropdown choose "grid results"
Set the font/fontsize to whatever you want (I use 12 pt Segoe UI)
Click "OK"

Answer (score 0):

currently there is no option but you can vote for this to be added into future versions here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1046535

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the sql connection box was really tiny. I tried using all the different font sizes for environment but nothing would fix the connection box size. What did fix it was a computer restart. All fonts went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the output of the print or select function, go to <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Fonts and colors</kbd> > <kbd>Show settings for:</kbd>, select <kbd>Grid Results</kbd> and change the field <kbd>Size</kbd> to a default of 7.