# How do I change the size of the text in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017?

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017

How can I change the size of the text that displays the database names and toolbars in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017 v17.4?

Comment: You might search at ServerFault.com to see if it's been answered there.

Comment: might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411992/sql-server-management-studio-object-explorer-how-to-increase-font-size